# UWP Vertical ScrollBar doesn't show up

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, scrollbar

I have a grid which contains several rows. In every row ther's some information. When clicking on a button on row=1 it expands and the lower part in my  app is collapsed. I tried to add a scrollviewer but still it is not shown. 
Here is my part of code where I add the scrollbar:

```
<Grid Background="LightSalmon" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
      ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">



    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Grid` does not scroll on its own, no matter what `ScrollViewer` attached properties you use. Remove all the `ScrollViewer` attached properties and put the `Grid` into a `ScrollViewer`.